# How to prevent buildings from moving on Google Maps Android API

Tags: android, google-maps

I've set custom overlays on Google Maps to get indoor maps of my building. But when I move the map on the screen, buildings are moving and overlays are fixed. So it gets a bit ugly. You can see how ugly it is on the image below.

[ugly indoor map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XzZ6.png)

I'd like to get the map like this : [pretty indoor map](http://mirandole.top/files/maps/)

How to prevent buildings from moving on Android Google Maps API ?

Below the part of code I use to set overlays on the map :

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private MapView mapView;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.mMap = googleMap;
    refreshGoogleMap();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

}

private void refreshGoogleMap() {
    mMap.clear();

    mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
          .tileProvider(new AssetsTileProvider())
          .zIndex(-1));
}

private class AssetsTileProvider implements TileProvider {
    private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 256;
    private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 256;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;

    @Override
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        byte[] bytes = readFile(x, y, zoom);
        return bytes == null ? NO_TILE : new Tile(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, bytes);
    }

    private byte[] readFile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        InputStream in = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = null;

        try {
            in = getAssets().open(getFilename(x, y, zoom));
            buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int read;
            byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            while ((read = in.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, read);
            }

            buffer.flush();

            return buffer.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // NO OP
        } finally {
            if (in != null) try { in.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
            if (buffer != null) try { buffer.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String getFilename(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        String level = currentLevel == LEVEL_1 ? "level-1" : "level-2";
        return level + "/" + zoom + "/" + x + "/" + y + ".png";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code? How are you adding your overlays?

Comment: I think you are not adding GroundOverlays as the API shows but probably in another way... please add some code

Comment: I've added the code. I use custom overlays but I'm going to try with ground overlays.

Comment: I have the same issue with GroundOverlay